# Is minitest part of the standard ruby distribution?

Tags: ruby, minitest

Is minitest part of the standard ruby distribution?
I tried googling but didn't find an answer.

Comment: Yes, minitest is included in ruby. You may still want to install minitest gem (to get a newer version)

Comment: As of 2.0 it is. Prior to that it was what is now [`test-unit`](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

```
ruby-2.4.1 ~$ irb
2.4.1 :001 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "2.4.1"
2.4.1 :002 > require 'minitest'
 => true
2.4.1 :003 > Minitest
 => Minitest
2.4.1 :004 >
```